# What does "The man behind the muscles" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Rita Skeeter's smile flickered very slightly, but she hitched it back almost at once; she snapped open her crocodile-skin handbag, pulled out her Quick-Quotes Quill, and said, “How about giving me an interview about the Hagrid you know. Harry? **The man behind the muscles**? Your unlikely friendship and the reasons behind it. Would you call him a father substitute?”

I don't quite understand "The man behind the muscles". Does it mean: *other than his muscles/power, what else does the man have?* What does it mean exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The [person] behind the [feature]" is a common phrase in journalism and other media referring to an intimate exposition of a person with some famous characteristic or history.

> The woman behind the mask
>
> The man behind the myth

etc.

Here the reporter wants to learn personal details about Hagrid other than his notable size.